# Bad performance of the model Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am working with a Boston housing price. I have my X and Y with a shape of (506, 13). Then, i define my model

```
def basic_model_1():
    t_model = Sequential()
    t_model.add(Dense(13, activation="tanh", input_dim = 13))
    t_model.add(Dense(10, activation="tanh"))
    t_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    t_model.add(Dense(6, activation="tanh"))
    t_model.add(Dense(3, activation="tanh"))
    t_model.add(Dense(1))
    print(t_model.summary())
    t_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    t_model.fit(X,Y, nb_epoch = 200 , batch_size= 10, validation_split= 0.20)
    return(t_model)
```

When i run this model, i get pretty bad performance of val_acc 0.0098.  I changed activation function to sigmoid or relu. Performance increases slightly. What do i need to increase model performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you could:

1) Add more neurons at every layer (use a multiple of 2 for better performance, try 64, 128, 256).

2) Add more dropout layers, one after every Dense layer.

3) Add much more data.

Comment: Just another quick question, when i try to predict model.predict(x[1]) otputs an error. Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question so that I can try to replicate the error more clearly; maybe by showing the database that you are using and so on =)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your model architecture. Only thing I would suggest is to use `kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'` in all Dense layers (specially in output layer) since it's a regression model.